references undefined when adding parts of pdf
With help from people in this website, I created this small package for personal use to add pdf as automatic appendix.
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesPackage{bilag}[2024/07/08 package to order appendix in danish (bilag) at the end of documentation]

   %%% 
   % built around tex stackexchange
   % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720328/71529

   \RequirePackage{expl3}
   \RequirePackage{pdfpages}
   \ExplSyntaxOn

   \tl_new:N\l_pdfpages_attachments_tl
   \NewDocumentCommand\attach{ m m m o }{
     \tl_put_right:Nn\l_pdfpages_attachments_tl{
       \includepdf[
         pages={\IfValueTF {#4} {#4} {-} },
         addtotoc={1, section, 1, #1, #3}
        ]{#2}}
      }

    \NewDocumentCommand\outputAttachments{}{
      \tl_use:N\l_pdfpages_attachments_tl
      \tl_clear:N\l_pdfpages_attachments_tl
     }
     
     \NewDocumentCommand\refAttachment{m}{
      \hyperref[#1]{\autoref{#1} (\nameref{#1})}
      }
    \ExplSyntaxOff

Here is a simple document (with a 200 pages of building materials catalog which happens to be exactly the one I use)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bilag}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

 Der henvises til \refAttachment{sec:beslag}, side \pageref{sec:beslag}.
 \attach{Beslag dok}{c-c-dk-2022-samlet-katalog-low-res.pdf}{sec:beslag}[40-42]

 \clearpage
 \appendix
 \outputAttachments{}
 \end{document}

When I add a whole pdf, no problem. When I add parts of a pdf, it gets added in the final complete pdf, except all references are fucked up.
I get this in the final pdf text : Der henvises til ⁇(⁇), side ⁇ (Document available in ??(??), page ?? )
I get this in logs :
Package pdfpages Warning: There's something wrong with the entries
(pdfpages)                of `addtotoc'. Not all entries were
(pdfpages)                processed. Check `addtotoc' on input line 65.

and :
  Latex failed to resolve 3 reference(s)
  Latexmk: ====Undefined refs and citations with line #s in .tex file:
  Reference `beslag' on page 2 undefined on input line 58

How to solve this issue ?

well the first step to solve the issue is to create a proper example that can be used to test the problem. You can e.g. use example-image-duck as example pdf. It has lots of pages.

Please note that \pdfpages_attachments is not a valid variable name under expl3 naming conventions. A variable should be named \(l|g|c)_<module>_<description>_<type> (with (l|g|c) being any one of those letters specifying the scope as local, global, or constant). So in this case something like \l_decembre_attachments_tl would be correct.

I modified the variable name after Skillmon comment. It made no change to the end result but standards are there for a reason.

you didn't test your example or you would have realized that hyperref is missing. Apart from this: the first argument of addtotoc must be the first page you insert, so addtotoc={40, 

You have to include all pages that are referenced in option addtotoc.
In your example you reference page 1 with addtotoc={1, ...} but page 1 is missing because you only include pages=40-42.

Would something like this work ?
addtotoc={\IfValueTF{#4}{#4}{1}, section, 1, #1 , #3}
It does not for me but I feel I am closer.

#4 contains a page range not a single page number. You need to extract the first number and then insert it (in expanded form) in your token list \l_pdfpages_attachments_tl.
